# pythonでseleniumのwindow_handlesがフリーズする

Tags: python, selenium

下記のコードでdriver.window_handlesがフリーズします。
常にフリーズするのではなく、１０回に１度程度の頻度で発生します。
エラーメッセージや例外の発生はありません。

やりたい事は、特定のタイトルを持つウィンドウに制御を切り替える
ことです。

データ依存があるのが分かっていて、このコードの前にボタンをクリックして
すぐに起動し画面がロードされるウィンドウが含まれる場合はフリーズが発生
します。画面のロードに時間がかかるウィンドウが含まれる場合はフリーズは
発生しません。

```
allHandles = driver.window_handles

for handle in (allHandles):
    print("*** title=",driver.title)
    driver.switch_to_window(handle)
    time.sleep(1)

    if ((driver.title == title) or ("エラー" in driver.title)):
        print("*** switch_to_window=",driver.title)
        break
```

回答よろしくお願いします。

Comment: プログラムの断片だけを提示するのではなく、他の人が問題を再現・調査出来るようなまとまったソースコードと、関連する動作環境の情報を記述するようにしてください。こちらのヘルプ記事を参考に。[良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: ちなみに関係あるかは不明ですがこんな記事を見つけました。`switch_to_window()`はかなり以前から廃止予定で非推奨な状態のようです。[Why is switch_to_window() method not working for selenium webdriver in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70360072/9014308) 代替手段はほんの少しだけ変わった`switch_to.window()`のようです。`to`と`window()`の間が`_`ではなく`.`になっています。調べてみてください。

Answer (score 0):

switch_to.window()にしている以外は同じ所でスタックしている者です。
try～exceptで回避しようにもその行でエラーも出力せずExceptionも出さずに困っています、回避策を発見なされたら教えて下さい。
ところで、察するに繰り返し実行なさっているかと思うのですが、WebDriverのプロセスが残っていたり、ブラウザのプロセスが大量に残っていたり、VS CodeあたりならPowershellもしくはPythonのセッションが、画面右側に溜まっていないでしょうか？ 一度、全て削除すると、フリーズ回避はできないにしても(私も知りたいです)、フリーズ発生頻度は減るかもしれません。